# Making a diamond with a line in the middle c#

Tags: c#, console, console-application, shapes

So I need to make a program that will print out a diamond shape with a line in the middle, the side is equal to the line, and the user inputs that value. I've tried to do it but can I can only print out a diamond without the line, or to make it in pieces, one hollow pyramid and one inverted hollow pyramid, but with that, I get a shape with 2 lines in the middle, any help is crucial!

example: 
input 5

output:

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*********
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

Comment: Please Include the code you tried with.

Comment: Now would be a good time to start using a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe its runtime behavior and the changing values of your variables.  When you do this, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What is that operation?  What were the inputs to that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  We can help with that, but Stack Overflow isn't here to just do your homework for you.  Please demonstrate and elaborate on the problem.

Comment: The idea of creating pieces is usually a good start. Maybe it could help if you add a 3rd piece. Piece 1: the upside (not including a middleline). Piece 2: The middleline. Piece 3: the downside (once again excluding the middleline)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DrawDiamond(5);
    }


    public static void DrawDiamond(int size)
    {
        int rowSize = size * 2 - 1;
        int center = size - 1;

        for (int i = -center; i <= center; i++)
        {
            char[] s = new string('.', rowSize).ToArray();
            int n = center - Math.Abs(i);
            s[center - n] = '*';
            s[center + n] = '*';
            if (n == center) { s = new string('*', rowSize).ToArray(); }
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

output:

```
....*....
...*.*...
..*...*..
.*.....*.
*********
.*.....*.
..*...*..
...*.*...
....*....
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: I did but I'm new to this site so it says that I need 15 reputation and I have 2....

Comment: @TarikRamadani Sure if you need some commets or something explain just ask me.